# Update the record if its duplicate row has maximum values

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

I've inserted unique records from one table to another table this way:

```
insert into unidata 
select distinct SourceFrom,Updated,Location_Type,First_Name,Middle_Name,
Last_Name,Designation,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,Pincode,STD_code,Extn,Fax_No,Office_Mobile_No,Website,Email_Office,Email_Personal1,Email_Personal2,
Residence_Address1,Residence_Address2,Residence_Address3,Residence_City,Residence_Pincode,Residence_STD_Code,
Residence_Phone_No,Personal_Mobile1,Personal_Mobile_NDNC,Work_Experience,Key_Skills,Personal_Mobile2,
State
from mytable src
where not exists(select *
             from unidata dest 
             where (src.SourceFrom=dest.SourceFrom and src.Updated=dest.Updated and src.Location_Type=dest.Location_Type
                    and src.Industry=dest.Industry and  src.First_Name=dest.First_Name and
                    src.Middle_Name=dest.Middle_Name and src.Last_Name=dest.Last_Name and src.Designation=dest.Designation and
                    src.Company_Name=dest.Company_Name and src.Address1=dest.Address1 and src.Address2=dest.Address2 and
                    src.Address3=dest.Address3 and src.City=dest.City and src.Pincode=dest.Pincode and src.STD_code=dest.STD_code and
                    src.Office_Mobile_No=dest.Office_Mobile_No and 
                    src.Website=dest.Website and src.Email_Office=dest.Email_Office and src.Email_Personal1=dest.Email_Personal1 and
                    src.Email_Personal2=dest.Email_Personal2 and src.Residence_Address1=dest.Residence_Address1 and
                    src.Residence_Address2=dest.Residence_Address2 and src.Residence_Address3=dest.Residence_Address3 and
                    src.Residence_City=dest.Residence_City and src.Residence_Pincode=dest.Residence_Pincode and
                    src.Residence_STD_Code=dest.Residence_STD_Code and src.Residence_Phone_No=dest.Residence_Phone_No and
                    src.Personal_Mobile1=dest.Personal_Mobile1 and src.Personal_Mobile_NDNC=dest.Personal_Mobile_NDNC and
                    src.Work_Experience=dest.Work_Experience and src.Key_Skills=dest.Key_Skills and
                   src.Personal_Mobile2=dest.Personal_Mobile2 and src.State=dest.State)
             )
```

This way it inserted records which were having exactly same duplicates like rows with exactly same filled columns. But there are records which are duplicates but with less or more records.

```
Email_Personal1 | Email_P2 |key_skills | state
abc@yahoo.com       null      null       null             
abc@yahoo.com       null      DBA        null
```

Above is the example, I showed up with only few columns. It applies to all the columns. Like few columns are having the same record in that row and its duplicate rows have few more columns with new values which I can't remove using above query.It takes such thing as unique records. I want to update the record with all the available columns from its duplicate rows and after that delete the removing duplicates rows. I want this way:

```
Email_Personal1 | Email_P2 |key_skills | state
abc@yahoo.com       null      DBA        null
```

Just store it as one final unique record rather than keeping two records as unique. Can anyone guide me here?

Updated (For Output):
[image]

Comment: Can you show more sample output from your query?

Comment: Can we consider `Email_Personal1` as a unique key&mdash;meaning that there should never be more than one row for each each `Email_Personal1`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, wait for a minute, I am going to update whole row.

Comment: @ZachVictor , but there are cases when there is no value in email_personal1 but still dupliates based on any of remaining columns. How to handle in that case? I am going to edit output in my question.

Comment: @iks_in Is there any single column that can act as a unique key?

Comment: No there is not. There was a SrNo,I've dropped the column as they were unique and incrementing, It didn't give me unique record while using distinct. Shall I add it again?

Comment: I don't think a serial number will help you. "Duplicate" is semantic or structural in nature. I am asking about the unique key, because the concept of a "duplicate" necessitates criteria for establishing uniqueness. In other words, you can't call something a "duplicate" unless you know in advance what makes a record "unique." What fields sufficiently define unique/duplicate?

Comment: @ZachVictor Thank you for guiding me. 3 columns of names(first_name,middle_name,last_name), email_office,email_personal1,email_personal2,personal_mobile1,office_mobile,personal_mobile2. These are the fields I can see duplicates are there mainly, I mean can identify based on these fields. Also I've updated my output image.Check it out.

Comment: OK, I think the problem is a row like the first row: the only unique piece of information is the `First_Name`, `'Sam'`. What would happen if you had four different records of four different people named 'Sam'—but with different Designation or Company, etc.? I guess what I am saying is that the data in the columns you gave me seem to be too inconsistent for any straightforward algorithmic solution. May I please suggest basing uniqueness on the email address columns **only** —and ignoring any row that lacks an email address?

Comment: Yes that's the problem I am facing. And even after spending so many days, I am still not able to find the accurate solution. Data is like this only. So messy.There are also columns where email ids are not there but mobile numbers are there.

Comment: and there are some data where only company name, designation, names are there, no cell number, no mails..

Comment: Or I can take whole data in resultset and then take another list or set then in for loop, insert first row in a list, then from next row onwards take one row from resultset and compare it with the existing row of list, if its same then check all the fields, update it accordingly. Insert this new list into unique data table. I am not sure but this may works..